# How do i handle error properly in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i wanted to know how to error handle properly. This is one block of my form. If i type in the field an already existing record in my database with the same team_name it gives me   Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry  error . I want to give a user an error below the team_name field that says this team name already exists with red letters.

```
<form method="POST" action="createteams">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="team_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Team Name') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="team_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('team_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="team_name" value="{{ old('team_name') }}" required autocomplete="team_name" autofocus>

            @error('team_name')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
```

the below code seems to work for my edit profile section . Is it because it updates  the database and doesnt try to insert like above?

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('users.update',$user)}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('patch') }}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="org_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Organisation Name ') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="org_name" name="org_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('org_name') is-invalid @enderror"value="{{$user->org_name}}">

            @error('org_name')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
```

edited controller

```
class CreateTeamController extends Controller
{
  public function index(Request $request)
  {

    $fName = DB::table('users')->select('org_name', 'id')->whereNotIn('id',[auth()->user()->id])->get();
      return view('teams.createteams',compact('fName'));

    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, [
          'org_name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:teams'
        ]);
      //get the current logged in user
      $user=auth()->user();

      $team=Team::create($request->all());


      //because App\User mopdel has a relationship teams we can directly attach means link a user to a team
      $user->teams()->attach($team);

      //then we check if any user was selected from the dropdown in the form if yes then iterate over each user
      if($request->get('org_select')) {
      foreach($request->get('org_select') as $org) {
        //find the user details from users table using App\User model
        $user = User::find($org);

        Mail::send('mail.notice',['user' => $user,'team'=>$team],
                          function ($message)
                          use ($user) {
                              $message->subject(auth()->user()->org_name." has invited you to a team");
                              $message->to($user->email, $user->org_name);
                          }
                      );
        \DB::table('team_user')->insert(['users_id' => $org, 'teams_id' => $team->id]);
      }
    }
      return redirect('viewteams');

    }

  }
```

Comment: You have to make it `unique` in your controller validation. And then, just get that error and show it. I think you shouldn't get an error about it.

Comment: hello and thanks for answering ... i ve added the line of code as u see in the controller, it doesnt show the mysql error anymore but it doesnt show the error in the view . It just does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use laravel validation in your controller

```
  $request->validate([
    'team_name' => 'required|unique:yourtablename',
  ]);
```

it will give "team name has to be unique error"

and to display error you can add this in your view

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: hello and thanks for answering ... i ve added the line of code as u see in the controller, it doesnt show the mysql error anymore but it doesnt show the error in the view . It just does nothing.

Comment: hello @Akil Patel it gives me an another error . SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `` = hello)

Comment: now there is some query in your sql query, it says a column name u have used is not present in the table

Comment: nevermind  i had the "," inside the ' ' instead of outside